# How To Use GetX Translations On Notifications(On Terminated State)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

GetX translation is not working on notifications that are created when the app is in the terminated state.

This is how I show the notifications. Below translations work in foreground notifications but not in the background (terminated)

```
showNotification(message){
   ...
   var title = 'some_title'.tr
   var body = 'some_body'.tr
   ...
}
```

And rest of the code, `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(onBackgroundMessage)` and `onBackgroundMessage` defined as required

```
Future<void> onBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
  showNotification(message);
  return Future.value();
}

void main() async {
  ...
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(onBackgroundMessage);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Note: I know, this issue is happening because the app is not running yet. GetMaterialApp did not run,  as a result, GetX didn't work too

Note: I'm not having any issue with navigations or showing notifications.

Comment: I have also used getx for navigation with push notifications, and I think it should have worked. Can you please share the code from where you're navigating by clicking on the notification.

Comment: I am able to show notification. I am able to navigate from notification click..The problem is with the moment the notification is generated, not the navigation.  I have already shared the code coverage necessary to understand the whole scenario.  Just focus inside the showNotification method.  The tr extensions that perform the translation do not work when the application is closed.  I'm highlighting the terminated state because everything works when the notification is built in the foreground.

Comment: This package is used in many parts of our project, like state management, navigations, translations, etc. So hard to change this skeleton now. And the saddest thing is the package has 600 on the Github repo. No one is participating or helping.

Comment: Hi, you found a solution ?